# How to add two arrays data in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, arrays, ionic2, angularjs-ng-repeat, hybrid-mobile-app

I am Beginner in Ionic 2. I want to add to array element as per their position.
for Ex: i have 2 array .

> 1. lables:[Lillium,Gerbera,Gerbera,Lillium,Rose,Rose]
> 2. Data : [10, 20, 10, 30, 20,10]

Now  I want to remove redundancy from labels[] and want to add their values from data[]

My final array should be

> labels: [Lillium,Gerbera,Rose]
>
> data : [40,30,30]

I have Extracted Data from Json this type:

```
 var qp = []
        for (var i of res.data) {
             qp.push(i.quantity_produced);
        console.log(res.data);
         console.log(qp);

        var name = []
          for (var i of res.data) {
             name.push(i.product);
              var s= [new Set(name)];
        console.log(res.data);
        console.log(name);
```

Comment: Whats the relationship between the data and labels?

Comment: Does every label have a value? Because this structure is pretty confusing, you're better off using an array of objects. Also to not have redundancy in the first place you could use javascript `Sets` which ensure will ensure uniqueness.

Comment: They are in single json thats provide names and production of flower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let labels = ['Lillium', 'Gerbera', 'Gerbera', 'Lillium', 'Rose', 'Rose'];
let Data = [10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 10];

//for each unique label....
let result = [...new Set(labels)]

//... get each occurence index ...
.map(value => labels.reduce((curr, next, index) => {
  if (next == value)
    curr.push(index);
  return curr;
}, []))

//... and reducing each array of indexes using the Data array gives you the sums
.map(labelIndexes => labelIndexes.reduce((curr, next) => {
  return curr + Data[next];
}, 0));

console.log(result);
```

Based on your comment seems that things can be done a lot easier

```js
let data = [{product: 'Lillium',quantity_produced: 10}, {product: 'Gerbera',quantity_produced: 20},{product: 'Gerbera',quantity_produced: 10}, {product: 'Lillium',quantity_produced: 30}, {product: 'Rose',quantity_produced: 20}, {product: 'Rose',quantity_produced: 10}];

let result = data.reduce((curr, next) => {
  curr[next.product] = (curr[next.product] || 0) + next.quantity_produced;
  return curr;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have extact lable and data this type: var qp = []
            for (var i of res.data) {
                 qp.push(i.quantity_produced);
            console.log(res.data);
             console.log(res.data);

            var name = []
              for (var i of res.data) {
                 name.push(i.product);
                  var s= [new Set(name)];
            console.log(res.data); @Vanojx1

Comment: But sir Our data is dynamic which is comes from json. As you suggest this perfectly work for static array. this is my json link: http://factoryunlock.in/sundar/public/api/v1/production @Vanojx1 sir

Comment: Your data can be dynamic, just replace data in my example with the data from your json.... [CHECK THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/2g31rta9/)

Comment: Sir can i pass json link instead of that static json responce  please Suggest@Vanojx1  sir

Comment: How to get json data via http its not related to this question... check the angular2 documentation for that